# Cannot See Class Library (.NET Core) in Visual Studio 2022 while adding/creating new class library projects

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, class-library

[image]

I have .NET Core 6 SDK, Runtime Installed in my System.
[image]

### Visual Studio Workload Components Installed:

#### Web & Cloud:

1. ASP.NET Web Development
2. Azure Development

#### Desktop & Mobile

1. .NET Desktop Environment

#### Other Toolsets

1. Visual Studio Extension Development
2. Data Storage and Processing

Comment: I would check workloads installed in VS and tried to reboot/repair the installation.

Comment: @GuruStron, Thanks for the prompt response. I have updated the question description with the workloads installed in VS. Tried with Restarting the System and repair the VS using VS Installer.

Comment: @GuruStron, Could you please confirm - https://i.imgur.com/8b485Wj.png - can we consider this highlighted box is also .NET core class Library from the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, it is. .NET is a "new" name for .NET Core since 5th version.

Comment: Thank You. If could you please post our discussion as an answer, I'm happy to accept.

Comment: Not sure what exactly should be the answer) the option was always there or it appeared after aforementioned manipulations?

Comment: Actually, in my online recorded learning video - it is shown as Class Library (.NET Core) and this is recorded during .NET Core 3.1 time so as you confirmed now .NET  or .NET Standard is a new version that works and I tried - it worked for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moving from the comments:

Since the 5th version "Core" part [was dropped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5) from the framework name:

> .NET 5 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1. We named this new release .NET 5 instead of .NET Core 4 for two reasons:
>
> - We skipped version numbers 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework 4.x.
> - We dropped "Core" from the name to emphasize that this is the main implementation of .NET going forward. .NET 5 supports more types of apps and more platforms than .NET Core or .NET Framework.

So you can use the ".NET or .NET Standard" option as shown at screenshot in your comment:

[image]